# numpy vectorization question on dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm converting a SQL row oriented python class from a row based calculation, to a dataframe pandas representation to parallelzie. In other words, I am taking the class and method and creating a wrapper function around that and also a vectorized helper.

I'm thinking about the best way to initialise the class with generic series of columns as defined in my `pandas` dataframe (df), but how would it be bested to write the signature for the **init** method of a class, I don't want to write out every dataframe column (i.e. `df[colA]`), but want to ensure that I am making the best of use of any parallelization. So how to avoid with many columns explicitly writing out: `df['colA'], df['colB'], df['colC']` etc

`def __init__(self, _id=None, colA, colB, ...):`

The helper functions are below:

```
def score(_id, bank_reconciled_ever_last_year):
 
  nv = NonVecClass(_id=_id, ...)
  total_score, score_breakdown = nv.score()
  return total_score
```

and the vectorization:

```
def np_vec_score(df):
  return np.vectorize(score)(
    df['_id'],
    df['colA'],
   ....

  )
```

Ideally I'd like to put out each row of the `df` to push into a python dictionary to work with the rest of the code.

I'm following example 7 from: [ml4devs](https://www.ml4devs.com/articles/pandas-dataframe-apply-function-iterate-over-rows/#:%7E:text=Applying%20a%20function%20to%20all,an%20axis%20of%20the%20DataFrame.)

Comment: You realise that `np.vectorize` does not parallelise code at all, and isn't even "vectorized" in the sense that it runs any faster than a regular python `for` loop? It's a badly-named convenience function

Comment: @roganjosh I'm refering to: https://www.ml4devs.com/articles/pandas-dataframe-apply-function-iterate-over-rows/

Comment: to get all the columns of a pandas dataframe, all you have to do is `df.columns` which gives you an index with the columns names.

Comment: @DBA_player I don't trust any of the numbers around that result in the article and, unless I'm being blind, I can't find how to run their full timing script despite several mentions that I can

Comment: Sorry, it's not really clear to me from the question what exactly is being asked for here. The overarching motivation seems to be to "parallelzie" but there's literally not a single parallel thing in anything shown. The most concrete part is about the class initalisation, but the problem to be solved here isn't clear at all - if you want to pass all the series of the df, why no just pass the df itself? Or is there some added complication, such as having to select specific series only? Showing a minimal but complete example of an unsatisfying but functional solution would be helpful. [...]

Comment: [...] The helper functions as shown seem completely detached from the rest. There's no parallelisation there, and it's unclear how they relate to the class. Is the `NonVecClass` the one that your question about `__init__` is about? If the question is how to pass `df['colA']` etc to a class, why does the code show passing it into a function? Please strongly consider to [edit] the question in order to make it clear what you actually want answered, as well as either closely integrating or completely removing auxiliary information and code.